# Convert Word to React markdown

Tags: reactjs, markdown, blogs, converters

Does anyone know of a way to translate Word syntax into react-markdown?
I am releasing a website to a client who is not very practical with writing using markdown.
So i thought maybe he could write the descriptions to add to the website on a Word file and then convert it into a markdown style and easy peacy.

Also, i tried to replicate this kind of list:

- List item

buy using either + or * or - but react-markdown doesn't recognise them.

Any idea on how to takle the issue?Any info are more than welcome. Many thanks

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for. https://github.com/sstur/react-rte

Comment: Hi Thanks, i tried that but i have issues with getting the data back from the database. Have a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64850515/draft-js-unable-to-get-data-from-the-database-cross-origin-error)  and the comments below, if you can. Thanks